# combinatorics problem formula, neighbors subsets

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Let $n \ge 2$ be a positive integer and let $S = {1, 2, ..., n}$. For $k = 1,2,...,n -1$, we call $neighbors$ two subsets of $k$ elements of $S$, if they have $k - 1$ elements in common (that is, differ by exactly one element). Let $f(n,k)$ be the size of the largest possible collection of subsets of $k$ elements of $S$, in which there are no two $neighbors$ subsets. Show that
$f(n,k) \le \dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$

I had this problem in a test. I tried to relate the formula in some way to the number of subsets that there can be without there being two neighbors, but I couldn't do it

Comment: Can you identify a collection of $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ subsets of $S$ that has the no-neighbors property? While that doesn't solve the problem, it might lend insight into a way to solve the problem. (The attack I have in mind uses induction.)

Comment: If k = 1, then $f(n,k)$ = 0 because all subsets have 0 elements in common. About the collection with $\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$, I didn't find it.

Comment: @GregMartin My answer shows that the bound $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ is not attainable, except when $k=1$ or $k=n$.

Comment: Can you post it please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, prove that
$$
k\times f(n,k)\le \binom{n}{k-1}
$$
The proof is as follows. Imagine a large table with $f(n,k)$ rows, and $k$ columns. Each row is associated with one of the subsets in the collection. For each row associated with the size-$k$ subset $U$, there are $k$ entries in that row; each entry is the size-$(k-1)$ subset that results from removing an element from $U$.

There are $k\times f(n,k)$ entries in this table, each of which is a size-$(k-1)$ subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Furthermore, the entries must all be *distinct* subsets, as a consequence of the no-neighbors property of the collection. Since there are only $\binom{n}{k-1}$ size-$(k-1)$ subsets in all, we conclude the displayed equation.

The above proves that $f(n,k)\le \frac1k \binom{n}{k-1}$. To finish the problem, we need only show
$$
\frac1k \binom{n}{k-1}\le \binom{n-1}{k-1}
$$
If you simplify this inequality by canceling common factors in the factorials of both binomial coefficients, you see it is equivalent to proving
$$
n\le k(n+1-k),
$$
which is easy to prove for all $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: Excellent solution! Can I ask what was the motivation for imagining the table $k \times f(n,k)$

Comment: It is a common trick. If you have a collection of things which are separated from each other by some minimum "distance", and you surround each thing with its set of "neighbors," then the sets of neighbors must be disjoint, because if two things shared a neighbor, they would be too close. This proves $\text{(# things})\times \text{(# neighbors/thing)}\le \text{(total # things)}.$ You see this a lot in coding theory, for example to prove the [Hamming bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound).

Comment: It also comes up in graph theory. In a graph with $n$ vertices, where each vertex has degree at least $d$, then the maximum size of an independent set is $n/(d+1)$.